# Uploading images with TinyMCE does not replace the src attribute inside the image tag

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, tinymce

**Update below**

I'm trying to upload images from my React frontend to my Laravel backend using TinyMCE the image plugin that is provided from TinyMCE. My backend and frontend are glued together with inertiajs.
The upload process works fine and saves the image, but when I try to save the form with the image inside of the TinyMCE Editor I get an error. This error comes from my backend where I first validate the request and then allow it to be processed.
This request fails because the image gets omitted as a base64 string inside of the `src` attribute inside of the `<img>` tag and the resulting string exceeds my max limit of 65535 characters.
Now strangely after that first unsuccessful attempt the `src` attribute wihtin the `<img>` tag has been replaced successfully with the location string from my backend and I now can save the form without a problem.

I will also provide a snippet of my current TinyMCE setup. My current implementation is that the image is first added locally as a blob and then uploaded to the server when the user saves the form. After that, TinyMCE should automatically replace the `src` attribute with the appropriate location string.

My current implementation is as follows

```js
 const submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    editorRef.current.uploadImages().then((uploadResults) => {
      if (!memory) {
        post(route('memory'), {
          onSuccess: handleSuccess,
          onError: (errors) => {
            console.error(Object.values(errors))
            handleError()
          }
        })
      } else {
        post(route('memory.update', { slug: memory.slug }), {
          onSuccess: handleSuccess,
          onError: (errors) => {
            console.error(errors)
            handleError()
          }
        })
      }
    })
  }

const handleSuccess = () => {
    toast({
      title: <Check className="text-blue-500"/>,
      description: !memory
        ? t('apiResponse.success.add')
        : t('apiResponse.success.text'),
    })
  }

  const handleError = () => {
    toast({
      title: t('apiResponse.error.title')
    })
  }
```

Is there something wrong with how I'm handling the Promise?

I am grateful for anyone's efforts to point me in the right direction. I have spent hours trying to fix this problem. I just can't seem to get behind it.
If you need additional context, please ask. I'm more than happy to provide it.

I have already tried setting the state of body manually and replacing the base64 string with the url from the promise result

```js
async function uploadImages() {
  const results = await editorRef.current.uploadImages();
  const body= data.body; // Create a copy of the state

  for (const result of results) {
    if (result.status === true) {
      const imageUrl = result.uploadUri;
      updatedBody = updatedBody.replace(result.blobInfo.base64(), imageUrl);
    }
  }

  setData('body', updatedBody);
  return results.map(result => result.status === true);
}
```

and then using it like this:

```js
const submit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  try {
    const uploadResults = await uploadImages();

    if (uploadResults.every(value => value)) {
      if (typeof memory === 'undefined') {
        post(route('memory'), { onSuccess: handleSuccess });
      } else {
        patch(route('memory.update', { slug: memory.slug }), { onSuccess: handleSuccess });
      }
    } else {
      toast({ title: t('apiResponse.error.title') });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error during image uploads:', error);
  }
};
```

Here is my TinyMCE implementation:

```js
<Editor
  init={{
    file_picker_types: 'image',
    relative_urls: false,
    remove_script_host: false,
    document_base_url: '../',
    images_upload_handler: handleImageUpload,
    images_upload_url: route('file.store'),
    automatic_uploads: false,
  }}
/>

const handleImageUpload = (blobInfo, progress) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob())

    axios.post(route('file.store'), formData, {
      onUploadProgress: ({loaded, total}) => {
        progress(Math.round((loaded * 100) / total))
      },
      withXSRFToken: true,
    }).then((response) => {
      const { location } = response.data
      resolve(location)
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error:', error)
      reject(error.response.data.location)
    })
  })
```

## Update

Upon debugging, I discovered that the `onEditorChange` function isn't triggered after invoking `uploadImages()`. Despite implementing a method to update the body state, the body remains unchanged.

Here's how I integrate TinyMCE as a component in my form:

```js
<TinyEditorComponent
  onInit={(evt, editor) => (editorRef.current = editor)}
  init={{
    content_style: 'body { font-size:14px };',
    height: '100vh',
  }}
  onEditorChange={onEditorChange}
  initialValue={text}
/>
```

Here, the `text` value in the `initialValue` prop is simply a state derived from data retrieved from the database.

And here's the method I've implemented:

```js
const onEditorChange = (newContent) => {
  setData('body', newContent);
  console.log("Body changed:", newContent);
};
```

This method simply updates the state of the body, which is later sent via the request. Note that I'm using the `setData` function from the InertiaJS `userForm` hook, but I've also experimented with a conventional `useState` hook from React with the same outcome: the state data isn't updated.

Additionally, I have to manually invoke the `onEditorChange` method because TinyMCE doesn't trigger it automatically after `uploadImages()` completes. So, the submission process looks something like this:

```js
const submit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  editorRef.current.uploadImages().then((uploadResults) => {
    const updatedContent = editorRef.current.getContent();
    onEditorChange(updatedContent);
  }).then(() => {
    // Additional actions after image upload
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by sending the content directly to my backend using the inertiaJS router.
With this approach, I was not dependent on the data state of the inertiaJS `useForm' hook.